# I can't get the variable which is in url in text zone PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my link:

```
<td><a href="repondre.php?id=<?php echo $user['id'] ?>;">Repondre</a></td>
```

I want to display the result in my input text in the other page:

```
$id=isset($_GET['id']);
$reponse = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM demande_client where id='$id'");
$user = $reponse->fetch();
?>
<form action="" method="get">
<label for="field2"><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['mail']; ?>" /></label>
```

I always get nothing in the textbox.  What is going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `isset` function returns true or false.

Comment: it show in top repondre.php?id=1; e.g  but i got nothing in text zone

Comment: `$id=($_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement

> ```
>      if(isset($_GET['id']))
>  {$id=$_GET['id'];}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

Change

```
$id=isset($_GET['id']);
```

To

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   $id=$_GET['id'];
} else {
   //generate error, id wasn't set
}
```

`isset()` returns a true or false response.

Comment: In the future, please accept the question that helped you as correct, for other peoples' reference.

Comment: I am arabic girl and I d'ont speek english very well and it's my first question here

Comment: Click the thing under the upvote and downvote arrows, on the left side of the answer. http://imgur.com/k2zsBlV . Forget about it lol, happy to help.

Comment: I visited the web site but i dont understand what you meen by under the upvote and downvote arrows